# Build Azure cloud solution for onpremise and datalake storage gen2 as source using ADF

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

what could be the ideal solution for the below scenario.

I need to build ETL pipelines using ADF, Onpremise sql Server and Datalake storage gen2(csv files) as sources, extract the data and provide to Reporting team(Power BI), on daily basis the pipeline should run

Is this possible to read data directly from on-premise to azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF can read data from on-premise SQL servers by using a Self Hosted Integration Run Time which runs on a server in your data center.

Documentation found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/create-self-hosted-integration-runtime